# Why my function doesn't return a new string?

Tags: python, string, function, replace

My assignment was to write a function with one string parameter that returns a string. The function should extract the words within this string, drop empty words as well as words that are equal to "end" and "exit", convert the
remaining words to upper case, join them with the joining token string ";" and return this
newly joined string.

This is my function but if the string doesnt contain the words "exit" or "end" no new string is returned:

```
def fun(long_string):
    stop_words = ('end', 'exit', '  ')
    new_line = ''

    for word in long_string:
        if word in stop_words:
            new_line = long_string.replace(stop_words, " ")

    result = ';'.join(new_line.upper())
    return result

print(fun("this is    a long string"))
```

Comment: could you give an example of desired output?

Comment: See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of `if` is never `True`, since `word` is not a real "word"; `word` in your code will be each "character" of `long_string`. So what `if` really does here is comparing `'t'` with `'end'` and so on. Therefore, `new_line` always remains to be the empty string as initialized.

You will need `split` to work with words:

```py
def fun(long_string):
    return ';'.join(word for word in long_string.split() if word not in ('end', 'exit'))

print(fun("this is    a long string")) # this;is;a;long;string
```

You don't need to check for empty words, because `split` considers them as separators (i.e., not even a word).

Answer (score 0):

`for word in long_string` will iterate over each character in `long_string`, not each word. The next line compares each character to the words in `stop_words`.

You probably want something like `for word in long.string.split(' ')` in order to iterate over the words.